# can I use eloquent model in foreach loop

Tags: laravel

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $source = Inventory_sources::where('code', $row['inventory_source_code'])->first();
            $source_id=$source->id;
            $product = Product::create([
                'type' => $row['type'],
                'sku' => $row['sku'],
                'attribute_family_id' => $row['attribute_family'],
            ]);
            product_flat::create([
                'product_id' => $product->id,
                'sku' => $row['sku'],
                'name' => $row['name'],
                'price' => $row['price'],
                'status' => $row['status'],
            ]);
            product_inventories::create([
                'inventory_source_id' => $source_id,
                'product_id' => $product->id,
                'qty' => $row['qty'],
            ]);
        }
```

error - **Trying to get property 'id' of non-object**
I try dd() its show the output.
how to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error you're getting because while add condition `code` = `$row['inventory_source_code']` sometime you're not getting records.

So you need to check the condition.

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $source = Inventory_sources::where('code', $row['inventory_source_code'])->first();
    if(!empty($source)){
        $source_id=$source->id;
        //your entire logic. 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your problem is that the $source variable could be sometimes null,

you must avoid use $source->id; when the $source is null

```
 $source = Inventory_sources::where('code',
$row['inventory_source_code'])->first();

if($source!=null)
{
// write the suitable code here ...
}
```